# CSS Select Selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Selecting for buttons works fine:

```
input[type="submit"]
{
    background:#efefef;
    width:auto;
    padding:5px;
    color:#666;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:5px 15px;
}
```

But I can't seem to get anything to work for drop down boxes, this doesn't work:

```
input[type="select"]
{
    background:#000;
}
```

Am I selecting it correctly?  Can you do it this way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
select {
    background:#000;
}
```

As I know, there is no `<input type="select" />`, just `<select></select>`.

Answer (score 1):

select NOT input[type=select] - browser offer differing capabilities on styling the select element so be patient