# input[type=select] doesn't work for me

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Select Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186155/css-select-selector)

I'm trying to add space on the left of my dropdownlist **without success**.

Here is what I tried:

```
.editor-field input[type=select]
{
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the selector is correct?

Comment: Well, go and look at your HTML, and tell me if you see an `<input>` with that type.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is no `input[type=select]`. You probably meant `select`, as in

```
.editor-field select
{
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

A `<select>` box isn't an `<input type="select" />`. It's a `<select>`;

```
.editor-field select {
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

should work.

Comment: Congrats on hitting 20k rep :)

Comment: @Ryan congrats on hitting 127k rep :)

Comment: congrats on hitting 137k rep

Comment: congrats on hitting 204k xD

Comment: congrats on 10 years of going up from 20k to 212k rep.

Answer (score 1):

Your "dropdown list" is surely a `<select>` element, not an `<input type="select" />`, which doesn't exist.

Try using `.editor-field select` instead.

Comment: select {margin-top:10px;}