# CSS styling input [type="??"] for select lists

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Select Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186155/css-select-selector)

What is the CSS equivalent to the following when dealing with select lists?

```
input[type="text"]
input[type="submit"]
```

Comment: Let's start at the beginning. How are you generating your HTML? You're not writing it by hand, are you?

Comment: No. It's AJAX generated. I'm experimenting with various means to have generic styling applied to multiple forms.

Comment: these inputs must be having some parent also or some other elements that can be used as reference

Comment: @Nick I thought so. But you can look at the source of the generated page with your browser, to see exactly what the result consists of. Very educational!

Comment: i topped it up for you. there are some mystery clueless-minusoners ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `input[type="text"]` CSS selector can be broken down into;

1. `input`; find all elements that are `input` elements.
2. `[type="text"]`; filter those elements by those which have the `type` attribute of `text`.

Because a select box is a `<select>` element rather than a `<input type="select" />`, you can just use the `select` selector as follows;

```
select {
    /* blah blah blah*/
}
```

Answer (score 4):

select is not a type of input like those in your example, so you cannot use an attribute selector when you target a `select`

Answer (score 2):

```
select {
   border:1px solid green; 
}

  select option {
     font-weight:bold; 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>As Fabrizio-Calderan says, select does not have a type property. however, you could use the data-property and style your element based on this</strike>

see here : [Select elements by data attribute in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css)

Why not using a class to style it?

Pseudo code:

```
<select>
    <option class="wise">
    <option class="not-so-wise">
    <option class="meh">
</select>
```